# Django & Apache2: Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, supervisord

I have a Debian 7.8 server running a Django (python) framework, using Apache 2.4.10 and also Supervisord 3.0. Python version is 2.7.9 although I use a virtual environment with version 3.4.2 for Django.

The server was recently restarted due to moving premises. After the reboot the Apache server will not re-initialise in supervisord. I can enter `supervisorctl` and it shows the error:

`FATAL ... Exited too quickly (process log may have details)`

When I attempt to re-run the process using `start *redacted*-apache` it simply fails again. Checking the logs with the `tail` command it shows the error:

`AH00526: Syntax error on line 211 of /var/www/supervisedserver/httpd.conf:
Invalid option to WSGI daemon process definition.`

I took a look at line 211 in the file and it is this:

`lang='C.UTF-8' \` or see the image in link:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23049542/file.png

for more information.

From a fair bit of googling I can see that the problem may be an issue with the "Nondaemonizing", or specifically not doing this, but I couldn't find anything else.

I'm unfortunately not terribly familiar with systems like these. I have development experience in python but mainly on Windows, with fairly basic understanding of the likes of Apache and high-level Linux operations. The servers were set up by my predecessor who didn't leave much documentation on the matter.

Sorry for the long-winded question. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I can provide additional info/feedback if required!

Alx